# is there an alternative for "List datatype" which can be sorted and performance popleft as a deque

Tags: python

i used deque instead of list for performance of `popleft`, but i have problem sorting deque since `sorted(deque)` will return a list then convert a list to deque again will blow the performance

my code:

```
from collections import deque

# items randomly added repeatedly and i want to get the smallest number every time
my_list = ['190-220', '101-189', '221-330', '2110-3300','0-100']
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))

my_list.pop(0) # not efficient since all the remaining items will be shifted in memory

print(my_list)
```

output:

```
['101-189', '190-220', '221-330', '2110-3300']
```

looking for performance, i tried to use deque but it doesn't support sort in place

```
# sorting, list is the winner here
my_list = sorted(my_list)  # return list, also we can sort in place by my_list.sort()
my_deque = sorted(my_deque)  # unfortunately will return list not deque
my_deque = deque(my_deque) # convert list to deque

# pop first item, deque is the winner here
my_list.pop(0) # not efficient since all the remaining items will be shifted in memory
my_deque.popleft() # it is the efficient way if we need to pop first item
```

is there an alternative which has the benefits of both "can be sorted as a list" and "performance popleft as a deque"

Comment: What's wrong with converting to list and back? The sort is going to dominate the cost anyway.

Comment: i think converting to list and back will make it less performance than using list instead of deque

Comment: how bad is the performance hit for what you are doing, have you quantified it with timeit or something?

Comment: Why not reverse the order of the list and use pop instead? Use l.sort(reverse=True) and l.pop(). Do you ever add items to the list after removing or sorting? Perhaps a heapq might be better if the task is to repeatedly remove the smallest item.

Comment: @VinceW., no i didn't timeit, my original choice was using "List", then looking for better way, i found deque but with a problem of sorting

Comment: @DanD., yes it is repeatedly adding, sorting, and removing, i will search for heapq, or if you have some info will be great

Comment: @VinceW., i already finished my application and it is working, just want to clean a lot of garbage in my code and add some optimization

Comment: @MahmoudElshahat, its a good question, and one I would like to know the answer to. I hope you find something helpful

Comment: It sounds like heapq is your best option here.

Comment: @user2357112, looking at heapq [docs]https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html, it looks like it won't work with my case, `my_list = ['190-220', '101-189', '221-330']`, i will update my question

Comment: The `collections` module in the standard library has , well, collections, including a deque. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @isaactfa, i tried to use deque but it doesn't support sort in place